# Code Mapping in Visual Studio 2015 by Function

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to add some AWS cloud back-end functionality to my app. I have it working in a sample and have tried copying everything relevant over to my app, but it isn't working. Is there a way of identifying all code referenced / linked to that function in my sample app, using Visual Studio 2015?

## Specific details of my problem

I am using AWS Cogneto Identity. When the login screen pops up and I log in, the screen goes blank and doesn't redirect to the next page. If I click "Done" (on iOS) at the top of the window, the FacebookAuthFailed event is triggered. In my sample, after sign in, the FacebookAuthSuccess event is triggered. Not sure why my code I copied from the sample should function differently to the sample, I assume I have missed some code somewhere, but VS doesn't flag any missing references etc. Hence, I would like to navigate through all relevant code in the sample.

Comment: "Not working" is the best ever problem description

Comment: @Jcl I know, I wish I had more info.

Comment: @Jcl Just using it as an example to try to better understand if there are tools for helping to solve this sort of generic problem.

Comment: It depends how it is "not working" that you may want to diagnose in one way or another. Does it not compile? Does it compile and run but not do anything? Does it compile and run but throws exceptions? In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: @Jcl It does compiler and run. I am using AWS Cogneto Identity. When the login screen pops up and I log in, the screen goes blank and doesn't redirect to the next page. If I click "Done" (on iOS) at the top of the window, the FacebookAuthFailed event is triggered. In my sample, after sign in, the FacebookAuthSuccess event is triggered. Not sure why my code I copied from the sample should function differently to the sample, I assume I have missed some code somewhere, but VS doesn't flag any missing references etc. Hence, I would like to navigate through all relevant code in the sample.

Comment: Have you tried step by step debugging? Those details should be added to your question, not expressed in comments, really

Comment: @Jcl I am not really after a solution to this problem, that isn't my question. I want to know if there is a way, possibly using code mapping etc. to understand which code is related to a function using Visual Studio

Comment: Well, you can definitely create code maps on Visual Studio *Enterprise*. I think there's limited support for it on Professional and as far as I know (I may be wrong), no support in Community, but I really can't help with that. More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396